# Select Box in a popup not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

We have a web application that has popup forms using AbsoluteBox and for some reason, only in Internet Explorer,  dropdowns do not open.  You can go through the contents with the arrow keys, but you can not see the selections or choose anything by using the mouse.  Firefox and Chrome have no problems.  Any ideas?

```
.absoluteBox
{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    /*background-color: #8a919e;*/
    background-color:#D6D7E7;
    border:solid 1px #4f6375;     
    -moz-border-radius:7px; 
    padding:5px 4px; 
    z-index:auto;            
}

loadForm('birth', 'birth', '', function () {}); 

<div id="birth" class="absoluteBox lfloat" style="left:20px;height:500px;"></div>
```

Comment: You need to show us an example of your markup and javascript - that way we can try and see what the problem is.

Comment: If it was up to me, IE wouldn't even be considered a browser, but clients...

Comment: @Musaab: Where is the rest of your code? We can't solve an HTML/JS problem with only CSS!

Comment: That's all.  You can click a button, it loads that div and displays that birth.htm page, and displays the form in the middle of the page.  That's it.

Comment: @Musaab, there must be more code—this is not a complete page. There could be some other code elsewhere that is interfering with what you've posted :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer has a z-index error. You must start at a real number (1) and go up from there. Auto may cause an issue, try either changing it to 1 or removing it completely. Z-index is inherited from the parent element, so if auto is your preferred behaviour, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it has to do with `z-index:auto;` Perhaps IE is not rendering the elements in front, and they are thus not accessible to the mouse (but form elements are always(?) accessible to keys).